# Stored Procedure Usage in Adobe LiveCycle ES

Tags: stored-procedures, adobe

We have a number of stored procedures in production that we would like to use with LC.  I reviewed the JDBC types and I don't see any way to get LC to accept the results of a call to a stored procedure, the stored procedure service only has an output for the number of rows affected.  In fact the only JDBC service I see that even handles results from a data base is the Multi Query XML one.

Is it possible to use stored procedures that return actual results in LC and if so how?

UPDATE:While it doesn't look like it's supported directly in LC it is possible to call a Stored Procedure from the XML Query activity.  Check out the comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the XML query with the proc:
[image]

Run the metadata fetch:
[image]